How long will it take for water to reach the coast from a dam bursting inland?
To give more context, I am referring to the Mullaperiyar dam in south India. it has been the topic of debate for a few years now and now the dam seems to be at its limits. There is a literal bulge in the dam that is visible from satellite images. But due to certain political issues, its repair has been postponed a lot of times. And now as of a few days ago, E. Sreedharan, aka "Metro Man", said that the dam doesn't need any repairs.
As a student who loves physics, I was curious as to why he would make this statement when the dam has reached such a state. I am also curious as to how much time it would take to reach my hometown, Kayamkulam, that is next to the sea. The dam is at an elevation of $881 \,\text{m}$ and is $85 \,\text{km}$ from the coast. Someone said to me it would take 15 minutes. Is that true?

The exact answer depends on the path that the water takes.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61S0KW7e-rc

The dam is 50 miles from Kayamkulam, so if the water reached there in 15 minutes, it would have to flow at 200 miles per hour. Seems unlikely. Also, I didn't look closely at the topography, but I question whether any water would reach Kayamkulam at all. Finally, I saw the "bulge" that you described in Google Satellite View. I'm not expressing any opinion about the state of repair of the dam, but I am not convinced that the bulge is not just an artifact of the way Google stitches their aerial photographs together.

For comparison, here are some estimates from historical dam failures (all taken from Wikipedia, so take them with a grain of salt):  Banqiao Dam, "nearly 50 km/h";  Johnstown Flood, about 65 km/h;  Vega de Tera disaster, about 100 km/h;  Malpasset Dam, about 70 km/h; Val di Stava, about 90 km/h.

Also, to follow up on Solomon Slow's point:  if the dam were to burst, the waters would most likely flow along the valley of the river that was dammed, the Periyar.  That river flows northwest to Kochi, and doesn't get particularly close to Kayamkulam;  which wouldn't be good for people in Kochi but might help you breathe a little easier, at least.

Google is a common citation for The Three Gorges Dam bending or flexing too. The 3D imagery frequently has issues with large elevation changes. I'd recommend using flat images over time. You can see some here that go from Sep-2016 to Aug-2023: https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/wayback/#active=47471&mapCenter=77.14524%2C9.52857%2C16
